# Loop Device eat up RAM

Tags: memory, loop-device, squashfs

**EDIT:** *Given link of another thread suggest that newer kernel do not have this issue but I am using latest kernel i.e. 4.18.5. Hence, this issue is either new or newer kernel have this bug*

In my setup, I need to mount least 200 Loop devices. Mounting 200+ loop device is not an issue. But I observed that mounting 200+ devices eats up almost 300+ MB of RAM.
All these loop devices are of squashfs type. 
Few devices are of size 1MB while few are of 50+MB.

`top` command also don't show anything about RAM consumption.
`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` also doesn't free up memory.

I would like to know that:

- Is this normal that mere mounting loop devices eats up memory ?
- Mounting 200 devices takes up almost 15 Sec. Is there any way to
  speed up this ? I am using the command: 
  *mount -o loop,nodev Sample.sq    /mnt/loop1*

Comment: Maybe you find it useful for your case [overhead of using loopdevice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278717/273268).

Comment: I am using kernel 4.18.5. Gcc 7.2

Comment: You are mounting 200 _squashfs_ images at once. I'm not surprised there's some memory ovehead and that it takes ~15 seconds, due to how squashfs works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS

Comment: You mention "few are of 50+MB".  What is the total size of all those squashfs filesystems, and how much memory would you expect them to take?

Comment: Total size of all squashfs images is around 1.2GB.